Healthkit Workout Session state not changing
My watchos workout app fails to prepare the workout session. No error is thrown in the delegate and the session state does not change. I have tried reseting permissions and health data but nothing works.
The reset function resets the session and builder which should solve the problem but dosent. sometimes it suddenly works however after a few workouts it stops working however if the error was caused by corrupted healthkit data resetting the simulator should solve the problem but dosent.
func prepare() {
        guard self.session == nil else {
            fatalError("Session already exist")
        }
        
        // Configure Workout Type
        let config = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
        config.activityType = .swimming
        config.swimmingLocationType = .openWater
        config.locationType = .outdoor
        
        self.Workoutconfig = config
        
        // Create Session
        do {
            guard store.authorizationStatus(for: .workoutType()) == .sharingAuthorized else {
                fatalError("Lack of permission to start workout")
            }
            let session = try HKWorkoutSession(healthStore: store, configuration: config)
            self.session = session
            self.builder = session.associatedWorkoutBuilder()
            Logger.diveController.info("Successfully created workout session")
            builder?.dataSource = HKLiveWorkoutDataSource(healthStore: store, workoutConfiguration: config)
            
            self.session?.delegate = self
            self.builder?.delegate = self
            
            if self.session == nil {
                fatalError("No workout session created")
            }
            
            if self.builder == nil {
                fatalError("No workout builder created")
            }
         
            self.session?.prepare()
            logger.debug("Session Started at: \(self.session?.startDate ?? Date())")
            logger.debug("Session State: \(self.session?.state.description ?? "")")
            if self.session?.state != .prepared {
                reset()
                fatalError("Failed To Prepare")
            }
        } catch {
            Logger.diveController.error("Error starting workout session: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }


func reset() {
        self.session = nil
        self.builder = nil
        self.state = .notStarted
        self.workout = nil
        
        self.waterTemp = 0
        self.activeEnergy = 0
        self.averageHeartRate = 0
        self.heartRate = 0
    }

